# How to change string-detection rule in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, disassembly, strings

I'd like to debug a Firmware (ARM-based) which contains a lot of C-Strings. IDA Pro 7.2 seems to have problems detecting strings having special chars (above 7-Bit ASCII) in it. Here is one example of the Spanish word "navegación", which has an diacritics "o" in it:

```
MAIN:0007AE4D                 DCB 0x4E ; N
MAIN:0007AE4E                 DCB 0x61 ; a
MAIN:0007AE4F                 DCB 0x76 ; v
MAIN:0007AE50                 DCB 0x65 ; e
MAIN:0007AE51                 DCB 0x67 ; g
MAIN:0007AE52                 DCB 0x61 ; a
MAIN:0007AE53                 DCB 0x63 ; c
MAIN:0007AE54                 DCB 0x69 ; i
MAIN:0007AE55                 DCB 0xF3
MAIN:0007AE56                 DCB 0x6E ; n
MAIN:0007AE57                 DCB    0
```

You see that 0xF3 is a valid ASCII char (ISO Latin-1), but IDA does not detect it as a valid char. If i now press "a" on the first letter (or let IDA doing a string detection), i would end up with this:

```
MAIN:0007AE4D aNavegaci       DCB "Navegaci"
MAIN:0007AE55                 DCB 0xF3
MAIN:0007AE56                 DCB 0x6E ; n
MAIN:0007AE57                 DCB    0
```

It see's the char as if it where a string-termination char.
How can i get IDA to as least ignore such special chars and just rely on my setting to show strings in C-Style (0x00 terminated)?

Answer (score 2):

You should open your IDA's `cfg\ida.cfg` file and look for the `StrlitChars` definition inside it. That configuration variable controls which characters are considered legitimate string characters when converting an address/array to a string.

Add your selected character in the format used and restart IDA.

The comment above the configuration variable is pretty straightforward, so following it shouldn't be an issue:

```
// the following characters are allowed in strings, i.e.
// in order to find end of a string IDA looks for a character
// which doesn't belong to this array:
// Note about CURRENT_CULTURE:
//  - if the IDB's default encoding for 1-byte/symbol strings, is not
//    UTF-8, a "culture" will be derived from it. E.g., "windows-1252"
//    will yield culture "Latin_1".
//  - this cannot be done automatically for UTF-8, since UTF-8 covers
//    the whole Unicode codepoints space.
//  - regardless of whether a "culture" can be derived from the default
//    encoding or not, this can be overridden by the CULTURE configuration
//    property (see below)
//  - the CURRENT_CULTURE directive tells IDA to consider all
//    codepoints that are defined as part of that culture, as valid
//    in the string literals.
//  - this applies to codepoints >= 0x80
//  - a "culture" refers to the name of a .clt file in the cfg/ directory.
//    E.g., "Latin_1" will correspond to the "Latin_1.clt" file.
//    In this case, the culture will contain all codepoints specified by
//    the file.
//    (It is worth pointing out that a culture file can, itself, include
//    other culture file(s))
```

As well as the [Official IDA documentation](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/news/7_0/docs/strlits/)